# As a US user, how can I change the default date format in Excel 2016 (Mac) to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2016

Note: I see several questions ([q1](https://superuser.com/questions/516271/how-can-i-change-the-default-date-format), [q2](https://superuser.com/questions/989370/how-to-make-date-yyyy-mm-dd-iso-8601-the-default-in-excel)) on this topic that describe how to accomplish this with the Windows version of Office, but I haven't found anything on Mac version of Office.

I'm a US user, and I want to change the **default** date format of Excel to YYYY-MM-DD so that if I open an Excel sheet or a CSV file with dates, it displays this format in the column. (In the case of a CSV file, if the format is already YYYY-MM-DD, I don't want it switch to the default format).

Alternatively, how can have this format show up as an option under Format Column -> Date -> US Dates?  I end up having to switch my country to Belgium before I can find this option.

(*<rant>*@Microsoft -- I'm pretty sure in 2016, people in the US use the YYYY-MM-DD format; at least make it an option!*</rant>*)

Comment: FWIW, I used the Feedback feature of Office 2016 to request this feature. Maybe others can do the same to help drive change :)

Comment: Under Windows, if you set it at the OS level, it applies as default to Excel too; I don't know for Mac. - If you don't want this for your whole system, you can add a format of the type 'date' and apply it to all places where you use dates; that is not *changing the default*, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that OS X's Language & Region "Short" date format controls how dates appear in Excel.

To modify how Excel formats ALL date columns by default to "YYYY-MM-DD":

1. Go to `OS X System Preferences` -> `Language & Region` -> `Advanced`
2. Change the "Short" date format by cutting-and-pasting the year to beginning
3. Change the separator character between the year, month, and date to -'s.
4. Use the month and day fields' dropdown feature to select the zero-filled version (e.g., "01" if your current month is January).
5. Restart Excel for change to take affect.