# Can I change the default excel time format from mm:ss.0 to mm:ss.000?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work with a lot of datasets from outside sources with times in the format mm:ss.000.

As such I'm constantly copying them into new workbooks, where excel will display the relevant columns as mm:ss.0.  Changing them is simple enough and quick enough, but my life would be fractionally better if I could make it DEFAULT (in any new workbook) to three decimal places.

This is about TIMES, not DATES, and because I'm talking about fractions of a seconds it's not possible to do via the locale/region settings in Windows' Control Panel.  At least, I don't think it is?
Possible?

### Update:

This question is different from this [similar one](https://superuser.com/questions/516271/how-can-i-change-the-default-date-format), as in regional settings it's not possible to choose a time format with decimals of a second.

Comment: Default format is driven by your regional settings (in control panel), need to change there.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate, please unmark it as so!

Comment: you can change also time format in regional settings. If you think your question isn't the same as the one it's identified to be, then please read it and it's answer and by editing it explain why that answer doesn't work for you. Editing will automatically place your question to the reopen queue.

Comment: You can, but not to fractions of a second you can't.  Not on windows 10 anyway.  I've already edited to make this clear...

Comment: Then the answer is no, you cannot.

Comment: I've edited your question and voted to reopen it. But it still need more votes to be reopened.